# updating react-scripts version from 3.4.0 to 5.0.0 causing Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getStackAddendum')

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, react-scripts

I am trying to upgrade react-scripts from 3.4.0 to 5.0.0 and it thrown issue when I do 'npm run start', **Type Error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getStackAddendum')**.
I am trying to resolve but unable to get rid of the issue. Does package installation order matters here or any dependency packages I need to look for while doing 'npm install'.

**we are using**
nodejs 16.14.0

**package.json**

react 17.0.2

react-dom 17.0.2

really appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#migrating-from-40x-to-500) run

`npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@5.0.0`

or

`yarn add --exact react-scripts@5.0.0`

and do not forget to delete your `node_modules` folder and reinstall your dependencies by running `npm install` (or `yarn`) if you encounter errors after upgrading